# Having trouble exporting and importing Oracle tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, impdp

I'm using Oracle 11 and I'm having trouble moving tables between two databases. I've successfully exported a datadumb as follows:

```
expdp.exe www/www@xe tables=TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3 directory=dmpdir dumpfile=tables.dmp
```

When I try to:

```
impdp.exe www2/www2@xe tables=TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3 directory=dmpdir dumpfile=tables.dmp
```

As a result I got the following exception:

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39166: Object WWW2.TABLE1 was not found.
ORA-39166: Object WWW2.TABLE2 was not found.
ORA-39166: Object WWW2.TABLE3 was not found.
```

If I try to:

```
impdp.exe www2/www2@xe remap_tables=WWW2:TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3 directory=dmpdir dumpfile=tables.dmp
```

I get:

```
LRM-00101: unknown parameter name 'remap_tables'
```

In my situation I can't use a database link. How can I change the schema when importing and exporting my tables? Have I somehow misunderstood Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `REMAP_SCHEMA=WWW:WWW2` and drop the `tables=` clause.

```
impdp.exe www2/www2@xe REMAP_SCHEMA=WWW:WWW2 directory=dmpdir dumpfile=tables.dmp
```

Comment: What if I want to remap the schema and just want to import a few of tables?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the [REMAP_SCHEMA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm#autoId37) parameter. The [REMAP_TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm#autoId38) (note the spelling) parameter is for changing the name of a table, not the schema it belongs to.

Comment: I had misunderstood the syntax. Thank you.